# Input, unable to retrieve input value React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

```
 Login(){
    alert(this.state.username);
    this.props.navigator.push({
        component: MainActivity
    })
    }



render() {
    return<View style={styles.loginView}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={require('./Ionic.png')}/>
        <Text style={styles.loginText}>Chat System</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.usernameText} placeholder="username" placeholderTextColor="black" onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username: text})} />
        <TextInput style={styles.passwordText} placeholder="password" placeholderTextColor="black" onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}  onSubmitEditing={this.Login} secureTextEntry/>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.Login}><View style={styles.loginButton}> <Text style={styles.loginButtonText}>Sign In</Text></View></TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback><View style={styles.signUpButton}><Text style={styles.signUpButtonText}>Sign Up</Text></View></TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback><View><Text style={styles.forgetPasswordText}>Forgot password?</Text></View></TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>

}
```

I need to get value of the username and password input, in the login method, when clicked on Log-In or pressing enter after entering password.

I am currently getting[this error while running in iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AffH0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and apparently a white-space over there:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.Login}><View style={styles.loginButton}> <Text style={styles.loginButtonText}>Sign In</Text></View></TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

causes the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It did work. Can you help me why i am not able to get the variable from username input field in my login method.

Comment: @Smit see my another answer to fix your problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible for you explain me? or put comments over the repo? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example: https://rnplay.org/apps/HVoVfw

You are executing `Login` wrong, correct way is:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.Login()}>
  <Text>Sign In</Text>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```